# Is heap memory in Linux contiguous?

Tags: linux, unix, memory-management, heap-memory, osdev

I was looking at the man page for brk(2), and it said that it increases the program break therefore allocating more memory to the heap. However, the way that I understand it, heap memory isn't always completely virtually contiguous in the PROG_TEXT -> PROG_HEAP (prog break) -> PROG_STACK manner that it seems to describe. Is the program heap actually virtually contiguous? If not, how does brk(2) work in a way that's consistent with what's described on the man page?

Answer (score 1):

Heap memory may or may not be contiguous.

1. `malloc()` is not restricted to `sbrk()` (`sbrk()` is what calls `brk()`...) The standard mode is the small heap comes from `brk()` and the big heap comes from `mmap()`; you are not expected to care about this as a user of `malloc()`.
2. The application may call `sbrk()` thus fragmenting the heap.

On 64 bit processors there's a pretty good chance of running out of RAM before `brk()` has to give up and `malloc()` resorts to `mmap()`; however this scenario can happen.

Your code really shouldn't care. If you're in a situation that's so degenerate that you care (I was once on 32 bit where I needed almost all my address space for a single workspace) you are whole program constrained and need to turn off ASLR for your process. If that's your question, answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1355819/287855

Comment: Yeah, that sounds pretty consistent with what I know - I guess I was asking if the small heap that brk() draws from is virtually contiguous and has a "break", vs. mmap() which may be fragmented across the address space...?